# Inaccurate for loop in Java array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I've tried many hours to solve array task, but it seems to me that I'm stuck. The task is to create a program that prints the number of given command line parameters and lists them.

```
You gave 2 command line parameters.
Below are the given parameters:
1. parameter: 3455
2. parameter: John_Smith
```

My program starts from wrong index + I'm not sure about the given task. How does the program know how many parameters to use if that hasn't been initialized? Or am I just completely lost with the exercise?

This is what I've done:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex_01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        int param = reader.nextInt();

        String[] matrix = new String[param];

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {

            matrix[i] = reader.nextLine();// This is the part where my loop fails

        }

        System.out.println("You gave " + matrix.length
                + " command line parameters.\nBelow are the given parameters:");
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(i + 1 + " parameter: " + matrix[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

And my own output:

```
3   //This is the number of how many parameters the user wants to input
2   // Where is the third one?
omg // 
You gave 3 command line parameters.
Below are the given parameters:
1 parameter: 
2 parameter: 2
3 parameter: omg
```

EDIT:

I DID IT! I DID IT!! After more Googling I found this:

```
        if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("no arguments were given.");
    } else {
        for (String a : args) {

        }
    }
```

Then I just modified the program and Voilà the program compiled. Here is the whole program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Echo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("no arguments were given.");
        } else {
            for (String a : args) {

            }
        }

        System.out.println("You gave " + args.length
                + " command line parameters.\nBelow are the given parameters:");
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(i + 1 + ". parameter: " + args[i]);
       }

        }

    }
```

I want to thank everyone who answered to this, the help was really needed! :)

Comment: Are you supposed to use the built-in args array?

Comment: Definitely! :D And hey thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command line arguments are not text read by the program with `Scanner` and the like, they are strings specified in the `args` array that is an argument to main. It seems like you need to output the contents of that array instead of reading input and outputting it.

Comment: Why are you doing other people's homework for them? It's not a good way to learn if someone just gives you the answers.

Comment: Yes, but he seems to be stuck on what "command line parameters" are. I'll delete my code and leave the guidance.

Comment: By the way do you guys know what is the best way to learn Java? I've tried various MOOCs, read over 20 java books, but seems that those haven't really helped me to understand fundamentals of Java.

Comment: @Javan00b Programming, and reading code. There's no shortcuts, and 20 books sounds excessive. There's only so much you can learn from books.

Comment: I would say this is a separate question, but it would probably get put on hold as "primarily opinion-based". I learned java from an [excellent tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm), then by going to the local library's book sorting warehouse and getting several Java books there.

Comment: I tried to run echo program from oracles website[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) but that didn't ask any input. I've problems to find more information how to use args to gain the desired result

Comment: @Javan00b I could teach you java, if you want. I'd create a chat room called "Let's Teach Javan00b Java", and teach you in the chat room.

Comment: @tbodt Yea sure! I just don't have enough reputation(20) to comment, but I'll try to increase it!

Comment: @Javan00b Reply when you have enough reputation and I'll create the chat room.

Comment: @tbodt Hi I just got enough rank(21) today :)

Comment: @Javan00b I'm responsible for that, I upvoted two of your questions. I've created the chat room, but it will take a few more days for the chat server to find out about your improved reputation.

Comment: @tbodt Hey thanks! :) I just sent request to join that chat room.

Comment: @Javan00b You have joined the room, and I'm in it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've confused what command line parameter means.  A command line parameter is a parameter passed to the `main` method when the program runs, while `System.in` is capturing user input at the command line as the program runs.

The command line parameters are passed to the `main` method in the `args` parameter, so for example:

```
java MyClass one two three
```

Would pass the array `["one", "two", "three"]` as the `args` parameter to the `main` method.

All you have to do then is use the `args` array to print the data information you require.

Comment: If I could I would also accept this as an answer, thank you! :)